how to search and count specific items in a Core Data relationship
In my Swift Core Data model, the first class has singers and the second class has the songs they wrote. If I wanted to count how many total songs there are, would I have an entity that stores all singers songs? Or would be there a way to search for all the songs in total in using just two Core Data entities?


You should have 2 entities.

@JoakimDanielson so there should be a singers, songs, and a combined entities making it 3?

Like I said, 2 entities.

Use 2 entities, Song and Singer. Add a many-to-many relationship between Song and Singer to track who sings which song. This allows for a singer to sing more than one song, and also allows for multiple recordings of a song by different singers. If more than one singer has recorded a particular song, you'd have one Song instance, and the singers relationship would have 2 connections.
